# What is the meaning of different ivar text colors in xcode's debugger window?

Tags: ios, xcode

Hitting the same breakpoint from two code locations... one is working and one isn't, and I think this color difference might be a clue. If I knew what it meant. But searching for this is hard:

Doesn't work:

[image: gray text: doesn't work]

Works:

[image: blue text: works]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it means the values of those variables were changed in the previous (or current?) step of execution. Your non-working example probably isn't getting the appropriate new values you want.